# Browsing remote repository in Nexus repository v3.x

Tags: nexus

Nexus repository v2.x had a feature called remote repository index and you could browse for all packages (not just cached) on your local Nexus repository.

Is this possible in v3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible because the feature was not added in v3.x. As of now we have to directly browse remote repositories (e.g. http://search.maven.org/).